# Laptop battery drains if asleep for long time

Tags: suspend, power-management, battery

I am running Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS on a Lenovo ThinkPad X1 Carbon Gen 8.

When the laptop is asleep and unplugged for a prolonged time (i.e., days), the battery drains completely to 0%. This not only is very bad for the battery health, but also it doesn't let me turn on my laptop once it is charged again unless I hit the hidden reset button.

Is there any way to force a suspend if the battery goes below a certain threshold and the computer is asleep?